# popover code in swift 3 not working

Tags: ios, swift

I tried to make a popover in swift 3 by creating a new view controller and present it as popover within another view controller, i have seen many tutorials but this code doesn't seem to be working on swift 3. Can anyone help? It seems that it gives me an error in the App delegate file.

[image: here I am creating the segue with identifier "popoverInfo" so if the Hola button is pressed, it should show the popover view controller]

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "popoverInfo" {

        let popoverVC = segue.destination
        popoverVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover
        popoverVC.popoverPresentationController!.delegate = self




    }




}

func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return UIModalPresentationStyle.none
}
```

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: @MoeAbdul-Hameed: OP says "not working", or just "error"? I'm could have sworn Xcode had more descriptive output in such situations; maybe a feature request is in order.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve a popover like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "popoverInfo" {

    segue.destination.modalPresentationStyle = .popover

    if let popover = segue.destination.popoverPresentationController {

        popover.delegate = self

        popover.sourceRect = // CGRect
        popover.sourceView = // UIView
        popover.permittedArrowDirections = .any
        popover.canOverlapSourceViewRect = // Bool
    }
}
```

However, Popovers will act like normal Modals on iPhone. Popovers will only work on iPad. (There are some ways to hack it but I don't know if apple would approve)

This code is adapted from a project I am currently working on, Let me know if it doesn't work for you and I can take another look.